# How to set a field value from parent template in Twig?

Tags: theming, 8

I have `node--article--teaser.html.twig` which calls `image-formatter.html.twig` to printout the `field_image`. Everything works fine except that I don't want the `field_image` itself to be a linked. i.e `image-formatter.html.twig` should not find a `url` to only print an `img` tag.

I have tried the following in `node--article--teaser.html.twig`:

```
{#{ content }#}
  {% set content.field_image[0]['#url'] = null %}{% endset %}
  {{ content.field_image }}
    {{ label }}
```

The second line causing the following error:

> Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end
>   of statement block" expected) in
>   "themes/saidbakr/templates/node--article--teaser.html.twig" at line
>   78. in Twig_TokenStream->expect() (line 87 of vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\TokenStream.php).

While `{{ content.field_image[0]['#url'] }}` prints the url without any problems!

The `image-formatter.html.twig` code is as the following:

```
{% if url %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ image }}</a>
{% else %}
  {{ image }}
{% endif %}
```

There is no any suggestion from twig debug about any alternative template for `image-formatter.html.twig`

Also using Theme Hook `image_formatter` as `saidbakr_preprocess_image_formatter` will not be an option because it is not possible to know the view context, i.e teaser or full, or content types to restrict this interaction for articles type. I think that the most simple way is from Twig, but how?!

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason to change any code for this, as you are using the default image formatter. You should be able to remove the link by going to `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/teaser` and change your field's formatter settings using the cogwheel-button and then select "None" for "Link image to".

Should the `teaser` view mode configuration page not be available, got to `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` and activate its checkbox on the far bottom of the page, then save and try again.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you have to think otherwise but this code will help you :

node--article--teaser.html.twig
{{ content.field_image | merge ({ 'url' : value }) }}